# regex split to split a string

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I need to split `"WUBWUBIWUBAMWUBWUBX"` such that I get the words `['I','AM','X']`
I tried using this line:

```
l=re.split("([W][U][B])+","WUBWUBIWUBAMWUBWUBX")
```

I got the output like :

```
['', 'WUB', 'I', 'WUB', 'AM', 'WUB', 'X']
```

Comment: And what makes you unhappy with the result? Note, that your expression can be simplified to `[WUB]+`.

Comment: `([W][U][B])+` => `(?:[W][U][B])+` would already [solve the issue](https://ideone.com/L3nx7a). You may also use `re.findall(r'[^WUB]+', text)`

Comment: Without regex `print("WUBWUBIWUBAMWUBWUBX".replace('WUB', ' ').split())`